# Crosstalk and EMI on a 2 layer board?

Tags: emi-filtering, via, crosstalk

I am new to PCB designing and was wondering about cleaning up crosstalk and EMI. Can I add ground vias between signals shown in the picture or will it be fine just to remove the ground vias in general? I know that adding a ground plane between both layers would work but making a board with more than 2 layers is not an option for me.  Also, the ground vias are connected to ground pours (second picture) between all traces. The vias are not floating.

Any advice or solutions is greatly appreciated.

Specifics: all traces are 1.8 voltage data lines at 50 MHz

[image: Signal traces routed on a two-layer board with stitching ground vias only]

[image: Signal traces routed on a two-layer board with stitching ground vias and ground pour]

Comment: Welcome! I need to ask, why _”but making a board with more than 2 layers is not an option for me”_?

Comment: Adding a ground plane between the layers actually probably wouldn't help as much as what you're doing here, actually. A ground plane between the layers is more effective at preventing crosstalk between traces on opposite layers, but with traces crossing orthogonally like this there's not going to be much crosstalk across layers to begin with--the crosstalk of concern is that between adjacent traces on the same layer.

Comment: The key principle to understand is that for every current there is a return current. Minimizing crosstalk is mostly making sure that a signal's return current has a path to flow as close as possible to the signal current.

Comment: I would not do a 2 layer 50 MHz board.  4 layers would be the minimum, if for no other reason than with that arrangement you at least have shot at determining what the Zo is of your traces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is on the right track!

This should give excellent signal quality, but it is of course rather intensive on via usage.  It would be nice to use fewer.  If you need absolute best signal quality, maybe this would be the way to go -- but a 4-layer board would be less effort (unless perhaps you have special reasons those are unavailable).  So you'll never see this in practice.

You can worsen it, incrementally, by pairing up traces into buses.  Or triple or more, etc.  This reduces the matrix significantly (via count goes as N*M for N top and M bottom traces crossing), and is still more than adequate for, say, LVCMOS signal levels (i.e., most MCUs, etc.), where the risetime is a few ns, corresponding to a wavelength of fractional meters.  So, very little voltage will be dropped along a trace at any given instant, over these kinds of distances -- including the image (ground-return) currents that may have to divert around the edges of the slots created in GND by the other traces.  (Which is a major part of where EMI and crosstalk come from in such areas.)

Also consider how much crosstalk is permissible.  Digital logic input thresholds are typically 30-70% of VDD, and output drivers are very close to 0/100%, leaving a 30% noise margin.  Parallel routed microstrip, at typical PCB tolerances, tops out around 10 or 15% coupling between traces, and at that, only for frequencies near the length of the coupling; i.e. if traces are paired along for 10cm length, then on the order of c/40cm or near a GHz, will have that degree of coupling.  It will be asymptotically (i.e. 20dB/dec.) less at lower frequencies.

So there's really very little risk for routing parallel buses, and anywhere you can afford a GND "shield" trace inbetween, that goes down considerably -- or even just plain old distance, since the field drops off quickly beside a microstrip trace (on the order of (substrate thickness)/(edge-to-edge distance)).

Conversely, anywhere you need extra signal quality, precision, bandwidth, etc. -- consider a cleaner layout, or 4-layer, etc.

For reference, a few years ago I built this display adapter. See the links below to my website.  It uses an Epson S1D13517 with support components (SDRAM and a serdes) for a parallel MCU interface to an LVDS LCD panel.  It's built on 2 layers, and as you can see, there was some... congestion, in areas.

Transparent layers: https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/DisplayCtrl_SDRAM_TopBottom.png
Top: https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/DisplayCtrl_SDRAM_Top.png
Bottom: https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/DisplayCtrl_SDRAM_Bottom.png

The top row of pins on the SDRAM (bottom chip) gets in the way of the traces reaching the far end; and there are a few VDD crossings in there (especially the one trace snaking along inside the top row of pins; note the bypass caps connecting along it).

The particular efforts I attempted here, are: making sure some ground pours between the bottom-side jumpers (up and down, crossing under the SDRAM top pin row); and allowing GND to stitch where traces/buses had to cross: in particular SDCLK, the longer trace down the middle; and VDD going to the graphics controller, off the top-right corner of the SDRAM, skipping 6 traces, layer swap, then 6 more traces.

Now, I don't have EMI results for this board unfortunately -- it was just a proto -- but if nothing else, I can confirm it is functional.

Answer (score 5):

Orthogonal tracks are great , interleaved ground tracks are great, with less crosstalk from adjacent and opposing tracks and lowers Zoand lower EMI.

With  high Zo you may have to limit track length or add series R to driver to match and prevent reflections or ringing.

Gnd vias won't do much. Nor will orthognal crosstalk be much if the source impedance is matched within 50%. For this layout.

### Experiment

Try probing a PCB logic level 50MHz with 10:1 probe and vary the ground length from 3mm to 100 mm . Or simulate  then add 50 to 100 ohms at source.

A Ground plane is better, but not always essential. Remember how L and C are created by ratios of length,area, and gap .If in doubt ask or look for commercial examples.

Try twisted pair magnet wire and use Falstads simulator to add 0.8nH/mm , source R and add a transmission line to learn with your theory in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Stitching the ground as you did:

- won't hurt
- probably doesn't help much with signal integrity because the routing seems already good for a 2-layer board (perpendicular crossing, ground traces between signal traces)
- can have small positive effect on EMC
- is likely overkill, a few vias will do

Comment: Stitching the ground vastly improves the performance of such layouts. Ground traces between signal traces are better than no ground traces, but for any practically sized layout, the vias will make a big difference when single nanosecond risetimes are put on the traces.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica why would that be? Those vias carry no return current because: a) The parallel ground traces carry it b) the backside copper can't carry it because there orthogonal traces lead to giant loops with prohibitive inductance.

Comment: 1) Via stitching as shown here does very little.  What is the vias connecting?  There are no GND planes involved, which is where via stitching is usually used.  2) I would never put single ns rise/fall times on a board without the proper GND and PWR planes.  Never.

Comment: And GND traces between signal traces is not necessarily a good idea.  Without the proper field solver analysis, you can't be sure that you're not setting up some kind of resonant structure that could be excited.

Comment: @SteveSh these vias do connect
GND patches to form a contiguous "plane".. usual 2-layer practice. And even without a solver I will be leas worried about a few mm perforated patch than about several long cuts in both planes

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it. The corners on the green traces should be at least 2x inter-trace spacing away from the red traces. **Only** cross the traces at right angles. The "mess" in the right half of the picture reduces performance.

If some of the traces come together after a crossing into adjacent pins of a chip, such as an MCU, then a fan works better: red traces fanning out from an MCU, and green traces laid out as *arcs*, perpendicular to the radial fan segments.